# JavaScript: Parse this string

Tags: javascript, text-parsing

Here is a long string (actually a JSON key value):

`"\u003cspan title=\"5 gold badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge1\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e5\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"8 silver badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge2\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e8\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"57 bronze badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge3\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e57\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"`

I need a way to parse it to get the number of gold, silver and bronze badges, using simple JScript in Dashcode.

Comment: It looks nothing like JSON to me. It appears to be an escaped HTML fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getBadgeCounts(s) {
  var badgeCountRE = /title="(\d+)/g, match = null, counts = [];
  while ((match = badgeCountRE.exec(s)) !== null) {
    counts.push(match[1]);
  }
  return {gold: counts[0], silver: counts[1], bronze: counts[2]};
}
```

Without hardcoded medal names:

```
function getBadgeCounts(s) {
  var badgeCountRE = /title="(\d+) (\w+)/g, match = null, counts = {};
  while ((match = badgeCountRE.exec(s)) !== null) {
    counts[match[2]] = match[1];
  }
  return counts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the string is:

```
   '<span title="5 gold badges">
        <span class="badge1">&#9679;</span>
        <span class="badgecount">5</span>
    </span>
    <span title="8 silver badges">
        <span class="badge2">&#9679;</span>
        <span class="badgecount">8</span>
   </span>
   <span title="57 bronze badges">
       <span class="badge3">&#9679;</span>
       <span class="badgecount">57</span>
   </span>'
```

Maybe you can add it to an unvisible div, so you can use DOM method to get the values you want

Comment: Seems he could load it into the DOM with `innerHTML=` then run a jQuery on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you put that string into a jQuery call, you can then query the document fragment just like you would any other piece of HTML:

```
var badgeHTML = "..." // Your encoded string here

var parsedHTML = $(badgeHTML); // Returns a jQuery collection of HTML nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

`var str = "\u003cspan title=\"5 gold badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge1\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e5\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"8 silver badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge2\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e8\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"57 bronze badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge3\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e57\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e";`

```
var res = {
    gold: 0,
    silver: 0,
    bronze: 0
};

/* using a RexExp
/                    - delimeter
(\d+)                - capturing one or more digits
\s+                  - one or more whitespace characters
(gold|silver|bronze) - capturing the color
/g                   - delimeter (global flag)

to match the information in the title of the spans
and using the replace trick to populate res
*/

str.replace( /(\d+)\s+(gold|silver|bronze)/g, function( all, count, color ) {
    res[color] += parseInt( count );
});

console.log( res ); // Object { gold=5, silver=8, bronze=57}
```